# В чем разница между createFromFormat('U', $date) и setTimestamp($date)?

Tags: php

Если мы введем такой код

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('2017-09-26 12:00:00'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "\n" . (new DateTime)->setTimestamp(strtotime('2017-09-26 12:00:00'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

То получим такой результат

```
2017-09-26 09:00:00
2017-09-26 12:00:00
```

Кто может объяснить такое поведение? 
И как здесь будет правильно работать с датами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока писал вопрос, разобрался с ответом. 
Дело в том, что `DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('2017-09-26 12:00:00'))` это статичный метод, который не видит наш часовой пояс. 
А когда мы пишим `(new DateTime())->setTimestamp(strtotime('2017-09-26 12:00:00'))` то в конструкторе объекта `(new DateTime())` часовая зона проставляется.
Для себя решил использовать такой код

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $time)
    ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()))
    ->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

U - означает "количество секунд с начала Эпохи Unix (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)" (см. [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php))

А UNIX основное время всегда считает в UTC.

Москва - это UTC+3

Поэтому первая функция выдает тебе ответ, исходя из того, что время задано в UTC, а вторая, исходя из того, что время задано местное.

Все правильно